# Multiple uisegmentedcontrol in 1 view not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a view with 2 uisegmentedcontrols, one along the bottom and one in the nav bar.  The bottom one is working fine, the one in the nav bar appears, but does not pick up any touch events.  Code for the bottom segment (working) is:

```
    footerSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil]];
[footerSegment setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 6, 310, 30)];
[footerSegment setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
footerSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
//segmentFiltering.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:80.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[footerSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[footerSegment setTag:0];
[footerSegment setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
UIImage *segSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_sel.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0];
UIImage* menuRightImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
[footerSegment setBackgroundImage:menuRightImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[footerSegment setBackgroundImage:segSelected 
                            forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage *segmentDividerImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"div.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
// Image between two unselected segments.
[footerSegment setDividerImage:segmentDividerImg forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
// Image between segment selected on the left and unselected on the right.
[footerSegment setDividerImage:segmentDividerImg forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
// Image between segment selected on the right and unselected on the right.
[footerSegment setDividerImage:segmentDividerImg forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[footerToolBar addSubview:footerSegment];
```

Code for the navbar one is below (visable but doesn't work):

```
    headSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
               initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil]];
[headSegment setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 7, 200, 29)];
[headSegment setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
headSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[headSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[headSegment setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[headSegment setBackgroundImage:menuRightImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[headSegment setBackgroundImage:segSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[headSegment setDividerImage:segmentDividerImg forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[headSegment setDividerImage:segmentDividerImg forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[headSegment setDividerImage:segmentDividerImg forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[headSegment setTag:1];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:headSegment];
```

Code for the action:

```
    -(void)segmentAction:(UISegmentedControl*)sender
{
    if(sender.tag == 0){
    NSLog(@"Selected index: %d", sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
    }
    else{
        if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex = 1) {
            NSLog(@"Selected HEAD index: %d", sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:headSegment];
```

That is not how you add things to a navigation bar. You must work by way of your navigation controller's `navigationItem`. You can make the segmented control its `titleView` or you can wrap it in a bar button item and make that one of the right or left buttons.

Comment: changed to self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = head segment;

Comment: How do you know? Your segmentAction implementation is not testing for every possibility. Put a log right at the start with no condition.

Comment: Still nothing, the bottom segmented control runs its log, but clicking on the nav bar segmented control doesnt even enter the action method

Comment: Got it!  this is what happens when you outsource development :( someone was overwriting the nav bar with a clear button that did nothing, ridiculous.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I was going to suggest something like that (actually I was going to suggest that other code was setting your `enabled` to NO...) Outsource or no outsource, there is always other code and it can do Weird Stuff... :)